# Can't connect between to access points set as bridge

Tags: wifi, access-point

Since years, I have a link between two locations, using a couple of Edimax EW-7206APg's. This worked reliably till a week or so, when the link dropped, and, after some debugging, it seems that one of the AP's power input capacitor blew. Voltage were strange, so I changed the filter cap by another low-ESR cap, and voltages normalized.

Still, there was boot-up but no link-up. Connecting an antenna, no stations could be heard, but the AP did seem to transmit. Maybe receiver blew?

Anyway, I had another AP (also EW-7206APg), so I reprogrammed it to take over:

- AP bridge - Point to point
- same channel
- Same ESSID
- Same security (later disabled to test)
- BSSID different but that's ok (I guess)

I'm at a loss why there's no link. Temporarily changing back to Ad-hoc shows normal local activity in the 'survey' (at both sides).

Any suggestion what else could go wrong? I'm quite sure I'm doing something wrong here.

One strange item: When I try to enable encryption, everything seems normal, but the 'Home' page of the model reports 'Security:  Disable' even though it is programmed correctly (and saved to the EEprom).

Answer (score 0):

Well... Solved. Documentation is really bad:

- The original modem, after repairing the power supply, transmitted normally, but reception was dead. I suspect the transmit/receive switch, but haven't had the time to test that.
- As mentioned above, both AP's have to be in `AP Bridge-Point to Point` mode
- Even though expressed rather poorly in the manual, the MACs for each of the modems have to be set to it's correspondent. I haven't found how to link more than 2 APs, though it *should* be possible.
- After 'Saving', it is *necessary* to also reboot (=power cycle) the APs (not documented), else the new mode does not get activated. So changing modes takes 30 seconds to save the new configuration, then a minute or so to reboot.